# using AES_ENCRYPT with VARCHAR in mysql

Tags: mysql, encryption, sqldatatypes

I am using `AES_ENCRYPT()` and `AES_DECRYPT()` for encription and decription of mysql data. Things are working fine no matter if I use `VARCHAR()` or `VARBINARY()` but this is just for small amount of data I am checking in. I have records which are already in `VARCHAR()` format and I prefer them to be as it is plus the detail I want to encrypt against those users are their Contacts and SMS, (which can as many as they want, to give you idea about possible size of data). Now if I use `VARCHAR()` with reasonable amount of characters length, would it be better to stick with `VARCHAR()` thing or somewhere/sometime I would have to shift to `VARBINARY()` due to some reasons or problems? Please give me good suggestions so that I leave this issue of `VARBINARY()` behind and keep using my `VARCHAR()` columns type ahead. Issue that made me to thing about it is when I google about it, I found mixed response from users, some say user `VARCHAR()` and some `VARBINARY()` while some has no issue at all and more worrying thing that MYSQL documentation prefers or what I say, `VARBINARY()`. I know that could be the reason because of data returns is in BINARY/BLOB fromat, but then why `VARCHAR()` type allowed at all? Hope will clear the idea of my question, thanks

Comment: Why are you using these functions at all?  What security benefit do you perceive that they bring?  Given that one must submit plaintext to the RDBMS, and that it returns plaintext back again, they provide little protection against virtually every conceivable attack vector (save for attacks at-rest, where the key is probably available somewhere on the system anyway).

Comment: the reason is to get data back somehow to see (in any case) using any other technique also gives option to get data back in it's original format but what's the plus point others have over AES_ENCRYPT?

Comment: Depends on your threat model, your application's requirement and the resources available to you.

Answer (score 3):

As documented under [`AES_ENCRYPT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt):

> [**`AES_ENCRYPT()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) encrypts a string and returns a binary string.

It seems pretty clear to me that the result should be stored in a binary string type column, i.e. `VARBINARY`.

As for problems that could arise from using `VARCHAR`:

1. depending on your character set, it's possible that some byte sequences are invalid and may be rejected; and
2. it's possible that unintentional character set conversion may munge your ciphertext.